# Accessing php without rebooting js

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please tell me there is such a link. /add.php?id=2 How can I do it without reloading the page, but that the php file is executed.

Comment: look into `ajax`

Comment: AJAX - HttpXmlRequest

Answer (score 0):

use ajax

from:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

```
   function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Javascript will execute that php file.

Ajax demo:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
Don't overuse w3schools. I'm giving you this for demo purposes